# ubuntu mysql setting problems

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Hi all I have ubuntu installed on my server with apache2 and mysql; every now and then I get this message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Connection refused 
(trying to connect via unix:///var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) in /var/www/fanta-trade/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1142 
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /var/www/fanta-trade/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1142`
```

I do not think is a script error because if I restart apache it starts working again. How can I solve it?

I add also the mysql log:

```
150719 11:05:52 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150719 11:05:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
InnoDB: mmap(17170432 bytes) failed; errno 12
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150719 11:05:52 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150719 11:05:52 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150719 11:05:53 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150719 11:05:53 [ERROR] Aborting
```

i setted

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 38M
```

Comment: trere will be probably some errors why it was refused in your mysql log in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: `150719 11:05:52 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` You are probably running out of memory. Is it possible?

Comment: it might be... i'm not good in balancing the server... any suggestion in what to hange... i have 2gb ram... i guess i can allocate more memory to mysql... but how much i do not know... and also... i that a way to periodically clean it?